# Combining 2 arithmetic sequences into one

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there a general method to find the formula of a sequence $a_n$ such as
'$a_n$ $=$ $u_n \cup w_n$' given the explicit formula of $u_n$ and $w_n$.
For example : $$u_n = 4 + 5n\iff u_n =\{4,9,14,19,24...\}$$ $$w_n = 7+3n\iff w_n =\{7,10,13,16,19...\}$$ $ a_n = ?\iff a_n =\{4,7,9,10,13,14,16,19,24...\} $

I'm not looking for a solution in this special case, but for a way to do this for every sequence.

Comment: are $u_n$ and $w_n$ increasing?

Comment: As n increases, yes. @cineel

Comment: So, if I understood correctly, that means that there is no general law for the union of two sequences, but in some cases, we can find one by analyzing?